# How to allow users to login in my site using their aol account?

Tags: authentication

i would like for people to be able to log in into my website using their aol account.

i went to their developer website and i fallowed the instructions,

now, in order for people to really log in into my website i need to grab their email and pass from their aol account and create an account on my website and redirect them there..

the only thing is that i can only grab the email.

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i need to grab their email and pass
>   from their aol account

I've got a sneaky suspicion that AOL won't hand that out to you!

You want to use AOL's OpenAuth implementation. This will allow you to auth users via AOL's system but they'll type in their username/password into AOL's site.

http://dev.aol.com/api/openauth

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and cleanest way would be using [OpenID](http://openid.net/). AOL [supports it](http://dev.aol.com/topic/openid).